# Lagrangian for Kerr-Newman black holes

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, black-holes, variational-principle, action

I am trying to write down the action that is extremized by Kerr-Newman solutions in General Relativity. Specifically, I am interested in parametrizing the Lagrangian by the mass $M$, angular momentum $J$, and charge $Q$ of the black hole. The first instinct of taking the Einstein-Hilbert action and substituting the Kerr-Newman metric, clearly cannot work.

I suspect that this problem might be related to the concept of minisuperspace, but I couldn't find any useful resources or guidance on how to proceed in this direction. Could someone please provide insights or references on how to construct the appropriate action for Kerr-Newman solutions, taking into account the parameters M, J, and Q? Any assistance or suggestions on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is the appropriate action not the Einstein-Hilbert action, and why do you expect an action to have those parameters, which arise from extremizing it?

Comment: @Ghoster KN is a solution for EH but I want an action whose only solutions are of KN family. So I guess I am looking for a symmetry reduced version of EH

Comment: see https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08682 at page 5 chapter 3, with the Nut parameter set to 0 this reduces to Kerr Newman. [Here](http://relativity.yukterez.net/66.html) you can find the requirend components for the metric and electromagnetic tensor and apply the equation from the PDF to them.